# Decryption of a Chef encrypted databag in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, chef-infra

I have been able to use the Ruby code written here [Data bag encryption encrypts on Chef server, but how to encrypt local copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849741/data-bag-encryption-encrypts-on-chef-server-but-how-to-encrypt-local-copy/13863457) as a basis to encrypt my data bags without having to resort to the knife tool which is great. My problem occurs however with decrypting these encrypting databags as the code written here [Data bag encryption encrypts on Chef server, but how to encrypt local copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849741/data-bag-encryption-encrypts-on-chef-server-but-how-to-encrypt-local-copy/13863457) doesn't appear to work correctly.

I have successfully downloaded the encrypted databag as a json, converted that to a hash, loaded my symmetrical secret key (which is used for both Chef encryption and decryption) and created a databag using this:

```
databag_item = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.new raw_file_down, secret
```

If I was to check the class of this `databag_item`, Ruby tells me it is a `Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem` object. However when I try to write this to a file

```
IO.write tmp_item_file, Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty( databag_item.to_hash )
```

i receive the following error:

```
Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem::DecryptionFailure: Error decrypting databag value: 'wrong final block length'.
```

Most likely the provided key is incorrect. When I remove the `.to_hash` option and do this:

```
IO.write tmp_item_file, Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty( databag_item)
```

I receive 233 or a 41. None of these methods produce a decrypted data bag. Can someone please help?

BTW I'm a new user to Chef

Comment: Are you calling `key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("path to file")` to load your secret key file followed by `Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("name","item",key)` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `raw_file_down` in `databag_item = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.new raw_file_down, secret` as actually a Hash and not a String or something else? Because the name suggests it's a file read into string.

Comment: Also provide us the encrypted databag - how does the file look like inside.

Comment: Please see gist trekr5 / gist:3afe8fe264a007f50665 showing sequence of decryption steps

Comment: I recommend using ChefVault, it is easier to use and more secure. https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-vault

Comment: what has been your experience of using ChefVault?